# Rewriting url after ajax call in a mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there any way to change the url after an ajax call. I have a page (eg., url - xyz.com/employees) which displays all the employees, and there is a link on the page named 'Add Employee' which returns a partial view. As this being an ajax call, the url remains the same, is there anyway to change the url to xyz.com/addemployee after returning the partial view??

Answer (score 3):

Many AJAX applications, such as gmail, use the hashtag (#) part of the url for this purpose.  You can change the url using javascript using `document.location`.  As long as the part of the url that is before the hashtag remains the same, the page will not refresh.  You will then need to build a javascript function that reads the hashtag from the url and opens the appropriate content. For example.

> http://www.example.com/Controller/Action?param=something

And when they click on the link to add employee.

> http://www.example.com/Controller/Action?param=something#add-employee

Next you would need to add a function that get called when to page is loaded to read the hashtag and open the appropriate partial page.

Comment: thanks matt for the quick response! actually I have added a custom route 'addemployee', this route points to 'addemployee' action in my controller.  This action checks whether the request is an ajax request, if so, it returns the partial view; else, the addemployee view. By this the user can directly type xyz.com/addemployee or go to default page (which displays all the employees) and the click 'add employee' link. Just to be consistent, I want the users to see xyz.com/addemployee always, no matter it is an ajax call or not.

Comment: As far as I know, most browsers are going to refresh the page if the url changes by anything more than the method I described above.